# How to recieve reactive mongo data using Rx 3.1.0v and pymongo python

Tags: reactive-programming

I'm trying to get observable mongo data using Rx 3.1.0, im trying to implement "Observable.from_" an error appear that "from_" is not recongized as observable method

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from rx import Observable

def collect_data(dbname, collection):
clt = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = clt[dbname]
col = db[collection]

colData= col.find().limit(10)
return Observable.from_(colData)
collect_data('test', 'money').subscribe(print(data))
```

an error appear that "from_" is not recongized as observable method

I'm trying to use rx.of

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import rx

def collect_data(dbname, collection):
clt = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = clt[dbname]
col = db[collection]

colData= col.find().limit(10)
return rx.of(colData)
collect_data('test', 'money').subscribe(lambda data: print('{0}'.format(data)))
```

I get

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x000001BF824FE8C8>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

> Observable.from_(colData)

i should replace with the new statement of RxPY 3.1.0

> rx.from_(colData).pipe(
>           ops.filter(...),
>           ops.distinct(...),
>           ops.take(...),
>           ops.map(...),
>       )

Answer (score 0):

[`find()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) returns a cursor which is an iterable; so use it in conjection with a for loop or similar. e.g.

```
for item in colData
    ...
```

or

```
list(colData)
```

Comment: im attempting to recieve reactive data, i already tried using **list(colData)** that convert output to a list

Comment: solution is instead of **Observable.from_** i should make **rx.from_(...).pipe(
    ops.filter(),
    ops.distinct(),
    ops.take(20),
    ops.map(...),
)**